# error in MenuDrawer Style

Tags: android, android-layout

i use this code

```
    <style name="MenuDrawerStyle" parent="MenuDrawer.Widget.Category">
    <item name="mdActiveIndicator">@drawable/menu_arrow</item>
    <item name="mdMenuSize">250dp</item>
</style>
```

and given this error
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'mdActiveIndicator'

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19855755/2892129) solution it looks very similar

> If you are using custom attributes for a gradle library then don't forget to
>   mark it as such. The gradle build file of the library needs:
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'android-library'
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'android'
> ```